# How to push git master branch to trunk of a new SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin in a Git repository: `https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-wordpress`

I would like to continue to use git for development. However I have to publish a copy to SVN in order to publish the plugin on Wordpress.org:
`https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/pushpad-web-push-notifications/`

I'm looking for the easiest solution possibile. The SVN repository is empty. I cannot use `git svn clone` because I don't want to create a new git repo.

I would like to simply push the git master branch to SVN trunk. How can I do that?

I've tried adding the following code to .git/config

```
[svn-remote "svn"]  
    url = https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org
    fetch = pushpad-web-push-notifications/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = pushpad-web-push-notifications/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = pushpad-web-push-notifications/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

However when I run `git svn fetch svn` git starts searching millions of revisions which refer to all the plugins hosted by Wordpress.org. So I have to kill that command. Also `git branch -a` doesn't show any new branch for svn. So I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

there u go.

```
git svn init <linkToRepositoryOrFolder>
git svn dcommit
```

the code in the git config for the svn remote should then be something similar to this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = http://mySVN/wordpresspluginrepository
fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

that remote is automatically added once you execute git svn init, the url has to be complete, not just the server root

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute:

```
git svn clone -r540813:HEAD -s --no-minimize-url https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-agenda/
```

Where `-r540813` is your first revision and `https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-agenda/` is a example of a plugin SVN repository at Wordpress

To get the first revision number, you can use:

```
git svn log https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-agenda/
```

And the first revision number will be displayed in the last commit on the console output